# php script from sh from crontab die with no traces

Tags: php, cron

in my crontab there is a script starting at 2:40 AM, executing some routines both from sh commands and php scripts starting from sh files.

the line in crontab looks like this:

```
SHELL=/BIN/BASH
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/mypath

40 2 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.twoam
```

inside the folder cron.twoam there is one script, let's call it script1:
inside script 1 some other scripts get called, and they are executed fine.
Then it comes time of this script let's call it script2, called from script1.
i leave traces both on txt files and system logs to check what happens.

```
echo "exec script2" >> /mypath/txtlog
/mypath/script2 > /mypath/txtlog2
echo "end of script2" >> /mypath/txtlog
logger -p local1.info "09@ script2 executed"
echo "end of crontwoam" >> /mypath/txtlog
date >> /mypath/txtlog
```

.... other script that runs fine

now let's see what is inside script2:

```
some scripts....
/mypath/subpath/script3
other scripts...
```

now let's check script3:

```
various php commands
cd /phppath/
php /phppath/myscript.php >> /mypath/myphplog
php /phppath/otherscript.php >> /mypath/myphplog
```

other commands

and finally comes the php script. the php script has various included script. every one of them execute normally except one. whenever i put it from line 2 to line 90 the execution will silently stop there.

so it comes the part where i do

```
include("phpscript2.php");
```

and things after does not get executed.

phpscripts2.php runs fine if executed by command line
with `php phpscripts2.php` by my user or by root.

inside phpscripts2 there is ( i include meaningfull parts):

echo "started phpscripts2"
exec("mysqldump ......");
ftp_connect();
file_get_contents("https://someotherscriptsondifferentserver");
echo "ended phpscripts2"

now what i find in logs:
in /mypath/txtlog i found both

```
exec script2
```

and

```
end of script 2
```

in myphplog i found

```
started phpscript2
```

and row after

```
started otherphpscript
```

i' m missing end of phpscript2 that end prematurly.
run time of phpscript2 is about 2 minutes.

i can't find traces in any log of some error.
where could i look?

EDIT:

i forgot to add that if make a sh file that calls just this script, and i make a custom crontab line to call it just for test, everything runs.

Comment: You should instrument your phpscript2 some more and attempt to find out how far it gets. You should also probably capture the file output of the script etc.

Comment: what is fill output? if the script output anything like a warning it gets logged in txtfile.

Comment: You're not capturing stderr in the script so that should be sent by email to the cron file's owner. To capture stderr use 2>&1 to send to the same file as stdout or 2> /some/other/file

Comment: php is like csh in one way: very finicky about its environment, control tty, and so on. i never got either kind of script to run inside cron, so i do what you're describing-- call the csh or php script from a sh script, and exec that sh script from your crontab.

in other words this is a known bug in cron, and always has been, and your workaround (gateway through a sh script) is what everybody does.

Answer (score 0):

> You're not capturing stderr in the script so that should be sent by
>   email to the cron file's owner. To capture stderr use 2>&1 to send to
>   the same file as stdout or 2> /some/other/file

This was the comment that lead me to the problem.

i redirected the stdErr in a text file and i could finally see it. I had a duplicate function that was coming out just in crontab. This because the full script had a series of require_once plus a lonely require. This was of no harm untill i added a small function in a common required file and i did not notice that there was still a require in place of require_once.
The error was mailed of course from crontab but i did not setup the sendmail yet so nothing was coming out.